# cosine similarity of documents with weights

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity, trigonometry

I am trying to find the cosine similarity of two documents represented as follows:

```
d1: [(0,1), (3,2), (6, 1)]
d2: [(1,1), (3,1), (5,4), (6,2)]
```

where each document is a topic-weight vector where topics are the first element in the tuple and the weight is the second element

I am not sure how to go about calculating cosine similarity in this case with this weighted scheme? Is there any module/package in Python that would let me do such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple idea is to create a vector of the weights, and then use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) to compute the cosine distance (which is equal to 1-similarity):

```
In [1]: from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: d1 = [(0,1), (3,2), (6, 1)]
In [4]: d2 = [(1,1), (3,1), (5,4), (6,2)]
In [5]: def get_weights(d):
   ...:     w = [ 0. ] * N
   ...:     for i, weight in d:
   ...:         w[i] = weight
   ...:     return np.array(w)
   ...: 

In [6]: w1 = get_weights(d1)
In [7]: w2 = get_weights(d2)
In [8]: 1-cosine(w1, w2)
Out[8]: 0.3481553119113957
```

Comment: If the vectors are long or there are lots of possible topics then you want keep them sparse -- otherwise it's dangerous to make them dense.

Comment: True, assuming the vectors are sparse, and there A LOT of topics.

Comment: @mdml - Thanks, the N I assume is the total number of unique topics? How can I find that? The number of topics can vary from case to case, I would probably need a way to count them apriori

Comment: @newdev14: exactly right, `N` is the number of topics. Should be simple enough, e.g. `max( d[0] for d in d1 + d2 )`

Comment: Yes, or see travelingbones answer/comments which has a similar way of getting N

Answer (score 1):

With a quick look there doesn't appear to be an off-the-shelf function that will take inputs of that form. You have two choices, which will depend on the problem, the size of the arrays, and other things. You can either convert each of the two topic-weight vectors to sparse scipy vectors and then use sklearn's cosine_similarity (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html) OR you can just write your own cosine_similarity. The way I would do the latter is cast each vector to a dict (for faster look-ups) like this.

```
import math

def vect_to_topic_weight(vector):
   return {a:b for a,b in vector}

def norm(vector):
   return math.sqrt(sum(vector[k]**2 for k in vector.iterkeys()))

def dot(a,b):
   return sum(a[k]*b.get(k,0) for k in a.iterkeys())

# returns the cosine_similarity, with inputs as topic_weight dicts
def cosine_similarity(a, b):
   return  dot(a,b) / float(norm(a)*norm(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are packages in python, e.g. [scikit-learn's cosine sim. documentation here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html). Below I've given you a manual way to do it:

```
import numpy as np

d1 = dict([(0,1), (3,2), (6, 1)]) 
d2 = dict([(1,1), (3,1), (5,4), (6,2)])

l = max(d1.keys() + d2.keys()) + 1 ## Number of topics observed 

v1 = np.zeros((l,))
for i in xrange(l):
    if i in d1.keys():
        v1[i] = d1[i]

v2 = np.zeros((l,))
for i in xrange(l):
    if i in d2.keys():
        v2[i] = d2[i]

## now v1 and v2 are 1-d np arrays representing your docs. 

v1 = v1/np.sqrt(np.dot(v1,v1)) ## normalize
v2 = v2/np.sqrt(np.dot(v2,v2)) ## normalize

cos_sim = np.dot(v1,v2)  ## should get .348155...
```

Comment: thanks, but the number of topics in your formula is the total across both documents, and not the unique number of topics...which is what is needed

Comment: you probably mean  : max(d1.keys() + d2.keys()) + 1?

Comment: your last comment is exactly what I have. to clarity, 
max( d1.keys()+d2.keys() ) = max( [0,3,6] +[1,3,5,6] ) = max( [0,3,6, 1,3,5,6]) = 6. We want +1 b/c the number of topics is 7 (0 is a topic).

Comment: as a general rule, use ipython, and type each line (or each element of a subline) in, and let it evaluate it so you can see what the code is doing.